# How to make a card/image selection like radio button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello I would like to know how to make a selection that works like radio buttons with wordpress. As in the image, the card on which the user clicks is the one chosen
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the images be `label`s to some hidden radio set. If you put the `label` element directly after the `input` element you'll be able to style it, such as with a border.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  
  /* ignore this, just in lieu of images */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <input id="img1" name="example" type="radio" checked/>
  <label for="img1">A</label>
</span>
<span>
  <input id="img2" name="example" type="radio"/>
  <label for="img2">B</label>
</span>
<span>
  <input id="img3" name="example" type="radio"/>
  <label for="img3">C</label>
</span>
```